# SMTP Reply At least one Recipient

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I have a problem with Replying mails with SMTP through PHPMailer. When I try to send the mail I get

```
"You must provide at least one recipient email address."
```

The following PHP Code I use is:

```
require("smtp/class.phpmailer.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();  // create a new object
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;  // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;  // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 465; 
$mail->Username = '****@gmail.com';  
$mail->Password = '***';           
$mail->SetFrom('***@gmail.com', '***@gmail.com');
$mail->Subject = 'RE: Hello World';
$mail->Body = 'Hello World';
$mail->AddReplyTo('****@gmail.com');

if(!$mail->Send()) {
    $error = 'Mail error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo; 
    return false;
} else {
    $error = 'Message sent!';
    return true;
}
```

I would like to know what else I'm lacking in the configuration.

Comment: Who are you sending the email TO?

Comment: I'm trying it to send back to the sender who sent the mail. Using the Reply-To

Comment: Replyto is not who you are sending it TO, it is who they will send an email to if they hit reply

Comment: So what does the ReplyTo actually do?

Comment: It sets the ReplyTo header value for your mail. It's like asking the recipient of your mail to reply to this address.

Comment: Like I said, it adds a header saying any reply to this email I am sending now, should be sent to the replyto address. Eg an email FROM: John saying I'm on holiday could have a replyTo of Sally who will answer emails whilst John is away and you would send that TO: customer@company.com, then when customer@company.com gets that email and hits reply, it sends an email to sally@somewhere.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AddReplyTo` is used to add a Reply-To address. Responses to messages you send with a *reply-to* address are delivered to that address.

Say, you send an email to one of your visitors with the reply-to address set to `support@example.com`. When they reply to that email, it will be sent to the email you specified as `AddReplyTo`.

If you're trying to send an email to yourself, you can just use `AddAddress` instead.

```
$mail->AddAddress('someone@example.net', 'JohnDoe');
```

Hope this helps!

Documentation: [phpMailer methods](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=methods), [phpMailer examples](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=examples).

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `To` address. You can add one like so:

```
$mail->AddAddress('josh@example.net', 'Josh Adams');
```

See a full example here: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer#a-simple-example

<sup>The `Reply-To` header designates the default/recommended address to use when the *recipient* clicks "reply."</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Use $mail->AddAddress() instead of $mail->AddReplyTo().